# Joining two tables so that it returns only one row from right table and all from left table for each match

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a SQL query which performs a simple left join based on the given conditions which is as follows

```
SELECT
a.Product,a.Grade,a.Term,a.Bid,
a.Offer,b.Ltrd

FROM CCS AS a 
left  JOIN LTR AS b ON  b.Product=a.Product
and b.Grade=a.Grade
and b.Term=a.Term
```

I have two tables CCS and LTR with following data

```
CCS Table

Id Product Grade  Term  Bid Offer
1  Xyz      A     Jan   20   30
2  XYz      A     Jan   25   35
3  abc      B     Feb   25   30

LTR Table

Id Product Grade  Term  Ltrd
1  Xyz      A     Jan   500
2  XYz      A     Jan   400
```

Upon running the above query it looks to match Product,Grade,Term and if all the three are equal, it performs left join and gives the following results

```
Product Grade Term Bid Offer Ltrd
Xyz     A      Jan   20  30   500 
Xyz     A      Jan   20  30   400
XYz     A      Jan   25  35   500
XYz     A      Jan   25  35   400
abc     B      Feb   25   30  NULL
```

above returned 5 rows and I trying to get only three rows that are in the table `CCS` with the lowest value of the column `Ltrd(ie 400)` in `LTR` table as shown below

```
  Product Grade Term Bid Offer Ltrd
    Xyz     A    Jan   20  30   400
    Xyz     A    Jan   25  35   NULL
    abc     B    Feb   25  30   NULL
```

In the above results in `Ltrd` column I just want the lowest value taken from the match in `LTR` table and assign it to `Ltrd` in first row and make other one `NULL`(in the above case 2nd row) and in third row it of course `NULL` as there is no match in `LTR` table

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a CTE. It is essentially the same query, but we use `ROW_NUMBER()` to a) break the groups up based on **Product**, **Grade**, and **Term**, and b) sort within those groups based on **Ltrd**. The sort pushes the lowest **Ltrd** value within each grow to the first row of each group, and then we just select the first row from each group.

```
DECLARE @CCS TABLE (Id INT, Product VARCHAR(20), Grade VARCHAR(5), Term VARCHAR(5),
                    Bid INT, Offer INT);
INSERT INTO @CCS VALUES (1, 'Xyz', 'A', 'Jan', 20, 30);
INSERT INTO @CCS VALUES (2, 'XYz', 'A', 'Jan', 25, 35);
INSERT INTO @CCS VALUES (3, 'abc', 'B', 'Feb', 25, 30);

DECLARE @LTR TABLE (Id INT, Product VARCHAR(20), Grade VARCHAR(5), Term VARCHAR(5),
                    Ltrd INT)
INSERT INTO @LTR VALUES (1, 'Xyz', 'A', 'Jan', 500);
INSERT INTO @LTR VALUES (2, 'XYz', 'A', 'Jan', 400);


;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT b.Product, b.Grade, b.Term, b.Ltrd,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER
          (PARTITION BY b.Product, b.Grade, b.Term ORDER BY b.Ltrd ASC)
            AS [RowNum]
  FROM @LTR b
)
SELECT a.Product, a.Grade, a.Term, a.Bid, a.Offer, 
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (PARTITION BY a.Product, a.Grade, a.Term ORDER BY a.Id ASC) = 1
                THEN b.Ltrd
                  ELSE NULL
       END AS [Ltrd]
FROM   @CCS a
LEFT JOIN cte b
       ON b.Product = a.Product
      AND b.Grade = a.Grade
      AND b.Term = a.Term
      AND b.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY a.Id ASC;
```

Results:

```
Product  Grade  Term    Bid  Offer  Ltrd
Xyz      A      Jan     20   30     400
XYz      A      Jan     25   35     NULL
abc      B      Feb     25   30     NULL
```

--

And just to have options, another way that might look nicer is to use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT a.Product, a.Grade, a.Term, a.Bid, a.Offer,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER
               (PARTITION BY a.Product, a.Grade, a.Term ORDER BY a.Bid, a.Offer ASC)
                 = 1 THEN c.Ltrd
       ELSE NULL END AS [Ltrd]
FROM @CCS a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) b.Ltrd
             FROM @LTR b
             WHERE b.Product = a.Product
             AND b.Grade = a.Grade
             AND b.Term = a.Term
             ORDER BY b.Ltrd ASC
             ) c
```

The results are the same. This might perform a little worse as `OUTER APPLY` runs the query inside of the parens (or function if that was specified instead of a query) for each row of the outer table. But sometimes it is good to see how these things work as it might help solve a different problem later. The `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` clauses can be quite helpful

Comment: My expected results did not match yours

Comment: @Dev If you want the same order as in the CCS table, then just adjust the ORDER BY statement in the 2nd ROW_NUMBER (currently showing as `a.Bid, a.Offer`). It could just as easily be set to `a.Id`). I just updated with the changes (what I just mentioned and an ORDER BY at the end). The output is now exactly as you have in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a derived table with the minimum value as source for the left join:

```
SELECT
  a.Product,
  a.Grade,
  a.Term,
  a.Bid,
  a.Offer,
  CASE 
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Product ORDER BY a.Id) = 1 
    THEN b.Ltrd ELSE NULL 
  END AS LTRD
FROM CCS AS a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Product, Grade, Term, MIN(ltrd) ltrd
    FROM LTR 
    GROUP BY Product, Grade, term 
    ) AS b 
ON  b.Product = a.Product
AND b.Grade   = a.Grade
AND b.Term    = a.Term
ORDER BY a.Id
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6243f/6)

Comment: This works fine but it outputs the value of Ltrd as 400 in 1st and 2nd rows. I just want it to be assigned to first row and keep other one as NULL

Comment: @Dev I just changed it. Did you try the latest version with the CASE statement? It should be correct now (and the sample fiddle gets the desired result).

Comment: Yeah it worked and what if I just want the same order that was in ny CCS table?

Comment: @Dev The result should be ordered by the CCS.Id which is what I assume the order in the CCS table, or do you want the results in a different order than what the SQL Fiddle gives?